# Conditionally add class using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the best practice way to conditionally add a class to an element?  One option is a if statement, and then add the class.  Another option is to add the class or add an empty string as a class.  Maybe there are better options?  Yea, I know speed is probably not important, but I just wish to know the "professional" way of doing this.

```
var addClass=1; //or 0
var row=$('#cloneElement')
  .clone(false)
  .removeClass('gone')
  .removeAttr('id')
  .attr('data-id',this.id);

if (addClass) {
  row.addClass('newClass');
}

var addClass=1; //or 0
var row=$('#cloneElement')
  .clone(false)
  .removeClass('gone')
  .removeAttr('id')
  .attr('data-id',this.id)
  .addClass(addClass?'newClass':'');
```

Comment: Both of these are equivalent. Make sure you always stick with a solution that would make sense for you and your fellow colleagues in 2 weeks time.

Comment: @bagonyi. I agree with sticking with one solution, thus why I asked the question so I can settle on one.

Comment: IMHO, sticking with the fluent interface for constructing the object makes for more legible code. That's the objective of method chaining. However the overloaded [`addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/#addClass-functionindex--currentClass) method may make for a more explicit, readable alternative to the conditional operator. `.addClass(function() { var newClass; if (addClass === 1) { newClass = "newClass"; } return newClass || ''; })` This all really comes down to personal preference, and team style, however. None of these is particularly obscure or obfuscated.

Comment: IMHO chaining frameworks should have `.addClass(..., condition)` methods ... because a lot of times we do have conditions inside the chain code. API devs take note.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion the first version is better. Probably that conditional is crucial to the correct operation of your page, and it is better to make it very clear and explicit, and not make it too obscure.

One of the most important things about professional code is that it should be *readable*, whether by your colleagues or by you in a few months.

So I recommend, when in doubt eschew the "clever" solution and instead choose the solution that is most obvious and simple and does not require any extra comments to explain it.

Answer (score 4):

In case you are using jquery ui you can use [toggleClass](http://api.jqueryui.com/toggleClass/)

```
row.toggleClass('newClass', addClass)
```

Comment: Thanks bagonyi.  I do use jquery ui, but typically resist using the methods if another solution exists.

Comment: If `addClass` is `false` and the element already has the `newClass` class then this will remove it - which is not the functionality that was being asked for.

Comment: @MT0 adding a switch to toggleClass will add or remove the class based on the `switch` being respectively true or false

http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/#toggleClass-className-state

`.toggleClass( className, state )


state
Type: Boolean
A Boolean (not just truthy/falsy) value to determine whether the class should be added or removed.`

Comment: @Hussam The OP's question was: if the toggle is true then add the class (if it is not there already) or if the toggle is false then do nothing - at no point are they removing the class (if it exists). The `toggleClass()` function will remove the class - which is not what the OP asked for.

Comment: @MT0, i guessed it was OP's intention to add/remove the class from OP's last line ```.addClass(addClass?'newClass':'');``` which would add newClass or empty string, but maybe he didn't express this entirely.

Comment: @Hussam That code snippet you quote does not remove a class and nowhere in the code or the OP's question is there a requirement to remove the `'newclass'` class. We should not try to second guess the OP but should be answering their question as they asked it; as such, using `.toggleClass()` is inappropriate for this task as it will remove the class and change the functionality of the code.

Comment: Currently JQuery supports natively toggleClass

Answer (score 1):

here's a simple function that will conditionally add/remove a class by passing a class name and boolean

```
jQuery.fn.applyClass = function(className,apply){
  if( apply ){
    $(this).addClass(className);
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass(className);
  }
  return this;
};
```

This is better than using toggleClass in cases where you might not know the state before toggling.

an example, say you want to show a navbar when you scroll 200px down

```
$(window).on('scroll',function(e){
    var top = $(window).scrollTop;
    $('.navbar').applyClass('show', ( top >= 200 ));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Either of the methods you have suggested will work.

This is an alternate method that allows you to chain multiple functions based on a conditional value:

```
var addClass=1; //or 0
var row=$('#cloneElement')
    .clone(false)
    .removeClass('gone')
    .removeAttr('id')
    .attr('data-id',this.id)
    .filter( function(){ return addClass === 1; })
    .addClass('newClass')
    .end();
```

Comment: Interesting.  I've never used `filter()` or `end()`, but probably should start doing so

Comment: @user1032531 - Please don't.  Code that uses `filter` and `end` is much harder to mentally parse.  Focus on code readability, not the fewest keystrokes to solve something.

Answer (score 0):

In newer JQuery, the best option is [toggleClass](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/), without jquery ui

```js
$element
  .toggleClass('newClass', addClass)
  .toggleClass('myClass', foo && bar)
  .toggleClass('callback', () => true)
```